# Swift 4 UISearchBar can't recognize lowercased 'i'

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to eliminate uppercased / lowercased search difference by lowercasing all strings when using **.contains** method. Also i am dealing with Turkish so we have uppercased "i" character. But it seems whenever **.lowercase** lowercases "İ" UISearchBar can't recognizes it.

For example; i have "BİLGİ" word at my database. If i try to search it like "Bilgi" it won't appear at tableView. Have to write "Bİlgİ" to get it. Every other character works perfectly but "i". Is it related with my database language preferences or is it something with .contains or .lowercase methods.

edit.

[here is the code part I'm dealing with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjLCA.png)

Also I'm using UTF32.turkish at database.

edit.

I played around a little bit and find out [whats wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qSPn.png) with it. Anyone knows the solution ?

Comment: Have you tried using `.localizedLowercase`? It should resolve your question. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414125-localizedlowercase

Comment: Please provide source code sample!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the .contains methods. the "i" with the "İ", it is a different character.

Comment: `.localizedLowercase` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Important

When working with text that’s presented to the user, use:
 `localizedStandardContains(_:) or localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(_:) instead.`

Comment: I implemented your code. It doesn't work. Actually i removed `.lowercased`, it works for any other character but "i".

Comment: Show me implementation.

Comment: this project is for my graduation project so its my first time that I got my hands on iOS developing. [implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVomx.png)

Comment: Did u try  localizedStandardContains?

Comment: yes i have tried it also. This bug drives me crazy.

Comment: Extension way : String {
    func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find) != nil
    }
    func containsIgnoringCase(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
}

Comment: Just try this way, I think it's UTF32.turkish issue.

Comment: Like i said, im beginner, can you explain how can i implement this into my code ?

Comment: Just create new swift file and put it there.

Comment: Please create little sample in gitHub and I try fixing it.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution :**

Since i'm dealing with turkish "i" character i use tr(turkish) identifier.

`let upperString = myString.uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr"))`

`let lowerString = myString.lowercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr"))`